# Unsmooth movement of sprite

Tags: java, 2d, slick2d

I am developing a 2D platformer game in Java/Slick2D.

Up until now my character moved a constant amount of pixels per frame.
I've tried switching to using the 'delta' variable (amount of time between frames), like advised, but the character's movement seems awfully jittery.

What can I do to smoothen the character's movement?

```
    private static final float DEFAULT_SPEED = 0.15f;

    Vector2f trans = new Vector2f();
    Input i = gc.getInput();
    boolean run = false;

    // X-Axis Movement
    if (i.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D)){
        trans.x += DEFAULT_SPEED * delta;
        lastMoveDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
    }
    if (i.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)){
        trans.x -= DEFAULT_SPEED * delta;
        lastMoveDirection = Direction.LEFT;
    }
    if (i.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LSHIFT)){
        trans.x *= RUN_SPEED_MULTIPLIER;
        run = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you defining delta? It should be how long it took a frame to draw / distance moved per second, or similar.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to solve it by divinding, like you said, instead of multipling by a float. I guess that it just doesn't look good with a floating-point number of pixels.

Comment: The reason interpolation works is that it evenly spreads your motion across your frames independent of frame speed. I doubt that having a floating point number of pixels is specifically the problem, but it could be.

Comment: Well, I'm just guessing, but since it's actualy impossible to move a non-integer number of pixels and anti-aliasing is in action, maybe the blur somehow causes this. I really don't know, but it's fixed now.

Integer division always gets me.

Comment: Just guessing that whatever api you're using to blit at some point will automatically cast your floats as integers before it gets to screen space.

Comment: Really? I thought that it's a common practice to interpret float position as a call to antialiasing.

Comment: You could be right! I'm making a lot of assumptions with my guessing. :) In my experience, with a wide range of API's, the only time I get crazy "anti aliasing"/distortions on sprites is when I do rotations.

Comment: Okay, thanks :). Actually, maybe you're right and the number is rounded, and then every few frames a pixel is dropped.